# How can I see all cron records in CentOs7

Tags: centos, cron

How can I see all cron records in CentOs7?
Is there a folder with a file that contains all the cron records?

Comment: This is a good tutorial I have found in top results in Google for the [centos crontab](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/automate-system-tasks-using-cron-on-centos-7/)

Answer (score 13):

You can find cron jobs from the following locations:

- /etc/crontab
- /etc/cron.d/
- /etc/cron.daily/
- /etc/cron.hourly/
- /etc/cron.monthly/
- /etc/cron.weekly/
- /var/spool/cron/

The last entry contains a crontab file for each user who is using crontab.

There is also a default log file for cron daemon, which will contain information about cron runs, `/var/log/cron`.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is CentOS 7 running systemd, you might also check systemd timers:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=timer
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following file to see the cron records :

```
/etc/crontab
```

Also look for files in :

`cron.daily`, `cron.d`, `cron.hourly`,`cron.monthly`, `cron.weekly` under `/etc` and `/var/spool/cron/`.

To see list of cron jobs under the current user:

```
crontab -l
```

To see the logs from `/etd/init.d/crond` refer `/var/log/cron`
For more refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users).

Could you please tell what are the contents in /etc/crontab.php?

Comment: Thank you, I have the `/etc/crontab.php` file, but it wal last upadted in 2014(!!) Is there a nother possible location where I can find the cron records?

Comment: The actual file could be `/etc/crontab`, so what does `/etc/crontab.php` contain? Also look for `cron.daily`, `cron.d`, `cron.hourly`,`cron.monthly` under `/etc` and execute `crontab -l`, if you want to check  logs, refer `/var/log/cron`

Comment: @saisasanka please edit your question to include additions to your answer.